# shlichim / shluchim

Tags: grammar-dikduk, chabad, vowels-nekudot

I've heard of Chabad emissaries referred to as both "shluchim" and "shlichim", though in the singular I've only heard "shaliach" (not "shaluach"). What is the grammatical explanation for this?

Comment: Hey, congrats on graduation! The former is presumably an extension of Galitzianer usage, which transforms the kubutz/shuruk into a chirik

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt But isn't the Hebrew word שליח Shaliach with a Chirik?

Comment: Yes, @DoubleAA, but the plural utilises a kubutz/shuruk.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Where?

Comment: @DoubleAA, של**וּ**חים

Comment: Maybe it's a corruption of the passive fem. form "shluchah" of which the plural should be "shluchot" and it became "shlicihim". In the same way that somehow the word became "talisim"*or "talitim") instead of "talisot" (or "talitot").

Comment: @DanF talisos, if anything.

Comment: Neither word appears in Tanakh. What makes you say it's Hebrew and not Aramaic and/or Yiddish?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2010/06/chaim-rapoport-review.html) (footnote 1):

> In their first endnote on the book Heilman and Friedman express surprise that Lubavitch emissaries are referred to as shluchim: “The precise Hebrew or Yiddish word for emissaries would be ‘shlichim,’ but for whatever reason, Lubavitchers have chosen to use the term ‘shluchim,’ perhaps to distinguish themselves from all other types of emissaries, religious or otherwise.” Heilman and Friedman, chapter 1, note 1. This comment bespeaks ignorance in the Hebrew language. Whilst it is true that in Modern Hebrew (the Ivrit of Ben Yehudah) the plural shlichim is used, in rabbinic Hebrew (and therefore Yiddish) it is virtually unused. The term shluchim and its derivatives are found in hundreds of places in rabbinic writings.

Comment: So what's the grammatical explanation?

Comment: See Mishna Rosh Hashana 1, 4: "-Pray to demigods or deities."עַל שְׁנֵי חֳדָשִׁים מְחַלְּלִין אֶת הַשַּׁבָּת, עַל נִיסָן וְעַל תִּשְׁרֵי, שֶׁבָּהֶן __הַשְּׁלוּחִין__ יוֹצְאִין לְסוּרְיָא"

Comment: Shaliach and Shaluach are two words. sometimes design the same object but maybe that Shaliach emphasize the din Shlichut and Shaluach emphasize the travel.

Comment: Isn't Shaliach basically sending something over, while shaluach is sending yourself over? Meaning, you are the subject.